# Why do I have a JS error "i is undefined jquery.datatables.min.js"

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, twig

Here is my HTML/twig:

```html
<table
    class="table table-striped"
    data-toggle="datatable"
    data-number-rows-display=5
>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-exportable="true" data-sortable="true">Nom</th>
            <th data-exportable="true" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
            <th data-exportable="true">Téléphone fixe</th>
            <th data-exportable="true">Téléphone portable</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for individual in people %}
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ individual.lastname }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ individual.firstname }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle"><div class="phone">{{ individual.homePhoneNumber }}</div></td>
                <td class="align-middle"><div class="phone">{{ individual.cellPhoneNumber }}</div></td>
                <td class="align-middle column-action">
                    <a
                        href="{{ path('people_edit', { 'id': individual.id }) }}"
                        class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#information-people-{{ individual.id }}"
                        >
                        <i class="icon ion-md-repeat"></i>&nbsp;Relancer
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use `data-toggle="datatable"` to toggle the DataTable on my array.

My javascript console is throwing me a warning `i is undefined jquery.datatables.min.js`. I don't understand what it means and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After passing my generated HTML through the the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/), I saw that I had too much `<th>` than `<td>` (6 `<th>` for 5 `<td>`). Deleting one of the `<th>` soved the problem.